# Chat room list layout suggestion

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, chat

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [StackChat chat-room display style](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57323/stackchat-chat-room-display-style)

It's "hard" for me to read the list of chat rooms. here's the typical path my eyes takes when I am seeing what chat rooms are active

[image: existing chat]

how about something like this instead? (not pixel perfect obviously - but y'all should get the idea i think)

[image: better maybe]

Comment: +1 would be a nice option at least.